# Query to List all hierarchical children with parent, grandparent etc. from entire table

Tags: sql-server, recursive

I have a basic sql table with an ID and an optional parentID from the same table. This has multiple levels. I need to get a list of all IDs with each of its parents all the way to the top.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#table') is not null drop table #table
create table #table (id int identity(1,1), [Name] varchar(16), ParentID int null)
insert into #table
values
('John',null)
,('Doe',1)
,('Mike',1)
,('Neil',3)
,('Sylvia',4)
,('Mary',2)

+----+--------+----------+
| id |  Name  | ParentID |
+----+--------+----------+
|  1 | John   | NULL     |
|  2 | Doe    | 1        |
|  3 | Mike   | 1        |
|  4 | Neil   | 3        |
|  5 | Sylvia | 4        |
|  6 | Mary   | 2        |
+----+--------+----------+
```

I need to get a list like this:

```
ID  | Parent | DirectParent
_______________________
2     1       1
3     1       1
4     3       1
4     1       0
5     4       1
5     3       0
5     1       0
```

- It ignores any record that does not have a parent.
- For each child there is a record matching it to one of its parents
- There is a bit column to know which parent is the one directly above it

How can I query the above table to get this data?

**Edit**: see what I have been working with

```
 WITH Recursives AS (
        SELECT   CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '\' ID,*       
        FROM    table
        WHERE   id=@ID
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  r.ID + CAST(t.ID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + '\', t.*
        FROM    table t 
        INNER JOIN Recursives r    ON  t.parentID= r.ID)

    SELECT ID,Name,Parent
    FROM Recursives r
```

I use this to get a list for a specific parent all the way down.

- I can't figure out how to do this for the entire table without
  getting an error 
   `The statement terminated. The maximum
  recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`
- How can I get the same child multiple times. Once with each parent?

Comment: You'll wanna use a [recursive cte](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You should give writing the query a try, and post back if you have any questions.

Comment: Also mention the SQL Server version you are using. Some of the new tsql functions might not be available in older versions.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik see edit

Comment: Okay, cool, go ahead and give us your test data as inserts.

Comment: Have a look at: OPTION (MAXRECURSION xxx). Try it by adding OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) after you select statement.

Comment: Do you have a hierarchy loop  somewhere in the data

Answer (score 0):

you just cannot do recursive on millions of rows.you have to put some filter

Try this,

```
F object_id('tempdb..#table') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #table

CREATE TABLE #table (
    id INT identity(1, 1)
    ,[Name] VARCHAR(16)
    ,ParentID INT NULL
    )

INSERT INTO #table
VALUES('John',null)
,('Doe',1)
,('Mike',1)
,('Neil',3)
,('Sylvia',4)
,('Mary',2)

    WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT id
        ,ParentID,1 DirectP
    FROM #table

    UNION ALL

    SELECT r.ID
        ,t.parentID,0 DirectP
    FROM #table t
    INNER JOIN CTE r ON t.id = r.parentID
    WHERE t.ParentID IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT r.ID
    ,r.ParentID
   ,DirectP
FROM CTE r

ORDER BY id
    ,ParentID DESC
```

Comment: Unless I'm completely mistaken, the only rows where `DirectParent` should be 1 are the rows taken from `#table` originally (in the first half of the CTE); you should be able to set `1 as DirectParent` in the part before the UNION ALL, and `0 as DirectParent` in the recursive part of the CTE, and avoid having to figure it out with the `OUTER APPLY`.

Comment: @RDFozz, Corrected.silly mistake

Comment: It doesn't return the desired result. http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9f4a8498b39f5b8f6c2e9598fae796a7

Comment: @McNets , see user desire output and "tried query" is misleading,I followed "desire output".you can easily exclude id 1 from my query.Why id 6 is not in output is not clear to me,but i am sure it can be easily filtered if [MB] clear it out.So far whatever is clear ,output is very much correct.[MB] is also struggling with Recursive.